# How do I set a countdown timer website that doesn't reset everytime I rest my browser

Tags: javascript

I've read a couple of articles and solutions provided online, including this very website but I'm either confused, or there's something I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to create a countdown timer, everything else functions very well, however, according to these articles and posts, my javascript is meant to save something so the timer won't reset every time I reset my browser.

Please assist.

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.extend({ 

      countdown100: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
          timeZone: "",
          endtimeYear: 0,
          endtimeMonth: 0,
          endtimeDate: 0,
          endtimeHours: 0,
          endtimeMinutes: 0,
          endtimeSeconds: 0,
        }

        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
          var obj = $(this);
            var timeNow = new Date();

          var tZ = options.timeZone; console.log(tZ);
          var endYear = options.endtimeYear;
          var endMonth = options.endtimeMonth;
          var endDate = options.endtimeDate;
          var endHours = options.endtimeHours;
          var endMinutes = options.endtimeMinutes;
          var endSeconds = options.endtimeSeconds;

          if(tZ == "") {
            var deadline = new Date(endYear, endMonth - 1, endDate, endHours, endMinutes, endSeconds);
          } 
          else {
            var deadline = moment.tz([endYear, endMonth - 1, endDate, endHours, endMinutes, endSeconds], tZ).format();
          }

          if(Date.parse(deadline) < Date.parse(timeNow)) {
            var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) - endDate * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + endHours * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
          }
          
          
          initializeClock(deadline);

          function getTimeRemaining(endtime) { 
            var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
            var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
            var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            return {
              'total': t,
              'days': days,
              'hours': hours,
              'minutes': minutes,
              'seconds': seconds
            };
          }

          function initializeClock(endtime) { 
            var daysSpan = $(obj).find('.days');
            var hoursSpan = $(obj).find('.hours');
            var minutesSpan = $(obj).find('.minutes');
            var secondsSpan = $(obj).find('.seconds');

            function updateClock() { 
              var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

              daysSpan.html(t.days);
              hoursSpan.html(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
              minutesSpan.html(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
              secondsSpan.html(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2))

              if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
              }
            }

            updateClock();
            var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
          }

          


        });
      }
    });

    

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: For context on what my current dilemma is, go to blackshadow.co.za which is my website.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! you could save your `endtime` variable into [HTML5's localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This way, it will be available until clear by the user or programmaticaly.

Comment: But from what i understand, you don't need to save the time remaining. You need to calculate it everytime the page is loaded.

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it already does what you want, no need to store anything. What issue are you seeing that you need to resolve?

Comment: everything is fine. But the clock resets when I refresh my browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I finally found what I did wrong and corrected that.